# How to get every frame storage size in video

Tags: python, opencv, video, storage

I want to figure out the bit rate per second in the video.
So I tried to do this by multiplying the frame rate by the size of each frame,

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
    frame_count = 1
    count_size = 0
    while True:
        success, frame = cap.read()
        if not success:
            break
        frame_count += 1
        row, col, depth = frame.shape
        size = float(row * col * depth / 1024)
        count_size += size
        print(f'frame:{frame_count},img storage size:{size}')
    print(f'count_size:{count_size}')
    print(f'os file size:{os.stat(filename).st_size}')
```

count_size:352170.0
os file size:518946
I didn't get the right result

**how to get real storage size of per frame**

Comment: wrong tool. you can't do that with OpenCV. use ffmpeg.

Comment: Which file format do you stream?

Comment: @Markus h265 format video

Comment: So what you are actually doing is to compare the size of the compressed file on disk (in bytes) with the sum of bytes that you received after uncompressing (in kilo bytes). That can't work. As Christoph already stated you need some API that allows you to access frame specific data directly from the decoder.